# Qt Creator/Linux: setting compiler/linker option -ldl for dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, linux, qt, dynamic, compiler-flags

I'm all googled out! Appreciation to anyone who can help me ...

I have built *test.so* and wish to call it dynamically using dlopen(), dlsym(), etc defined in dlfcn.h

I **can compile** my calling program (main.cpp) on the command line **without error**

```
g++ main.cpp -ldl -o myprog
```

Without the -ldl switch, I get the error: *undefined reference dlopen()*.
Also, if the -ldl switch isn't placed after the source file in the g++ argument list, then I get the same error.

My question is this: how can I compile my main.cpp in Qt Creator?
Qt Creator reports the same error: *undefined reference dlopen()*

I've tried directly adding -ldl to the flags in the Makefile (CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, LFLAGS) but to no avail. (Perhaps the flags are inserted before the source files where -ldl doesn't work?)

Here's my main.cpp :

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main()
{

   void* handle = dlopen("./test.so", RTLD_LAZY);

   return 0;
}
```

I'm using Qt Creator 2.4.1 on linux

Many thanks :)

Comment: With qmake, try adding `-ldl` to `LIBS`

Comment: Also show us the line from the Makefile that you tried.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `project_name.pro` file, you should add to the `LIBS` variable like so:

```
LIBS += -ldl
```